# Firebase chat app crashes when clicking on table cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I downloaded a demo chat application that runs perfectly but when I implement it into my own app it crashes and the code is exactly the same. The app gives you the ability to create a chat room and my app works up to this point but when you click on the chat room name that now appears on the table I get the following error:

> Assertion failure in -[Irish_League_Grounds.ChatViewController viewWillAppear:], /Users/ryanball/Desktop/Irish League
>   Grounds/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m:277
>   2017-05-17 17:32:55.815 Irish League Grounds[20456:681491]
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: self.senderDisplayName != nil'

Here is my code for the two view controllers I'm segueing between:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

enum Section: Int {
  case createNewChannelSection = 0
  case currentChannelsSection
}

class ChannelListViewController: UITableViewController {

  // MARK: Properties
  var senderDisplayName: String?
  var newChannelTextField: UITextField?

  private var channelRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
  private var channels: [Channel] = []

  private lazy var channelRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("channels")

  // MARK: View Lifecycle

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "RW RIC"
    observeChannels()
  }

  deinit {
    if let refHandle = channelRefHandle {
      channelRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
    }
  }

  // MARK :Actions

  @IBAction func createChannel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let name = newChannelTextField?.text {
      let newChannelRef = channelRef.childByAutoId()
      let channelItem = [
        "name": name
      ]
      newChannelRef.setValue(channelItem)
    }    
  }

  // MARK: Firebase related methods

  private func observeChannels() {
    // We can use the observe method to listen for new
    // channels being written to the Firebase DB
    channelRefHandle = channelRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
      let channelData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
      let id = snapshot.key
      if let name = channelData["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 {
        self.channels.append(Channel(id: id, name: name))
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      } else {
        print("Error! Could not decode channel data")
      }
    })
  }

  // MARK: Navigation

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    if let channel = sender as? Channel {
      let chatVc = segue.destination as! ChatViewController

      chatVc.senderDisplayName = senderDisplayName
      chatVc.channel = channel
      chatVc.channelRef = channelRef.child(channel.id)
    }
  }

  // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let currentSection: Section = Section(rawValue: section) {
      switch currentSection {
      case .createNewChannelSection:
        return 1
      case .currentChannelsSection:
        return channels.count
      }
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.createNewChannelSection.rawValue ? "NewChannel" : "ExistingChannel"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.createNewChannelSection.rawValue {
      if let createNewChannelCell = cell as? CreateChannelCell {
        newChannelTextField = createNewChannelCell.newChannelNameField
      }
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue {
      cell.textLabel?.text = channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name
    }

    return cell
  }

  // MARK: UITableViewDelegate

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue {
      let channel = channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChannel", sender: channel)
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the second view controller:

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import Firebase
import JSQMessagesViewController

final class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

  // MARK: Properties
  private let imageURLNotSetKey = "NOTSET"

  var channelRef: FIRDatabaseReference?

  private lazy var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference = self.channelRef!.child("messages")
  fileprivate lazy var storageRef: FIRStorageReference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://chatchat-871d0.appspot.com")
  private lazy var userIsTypingRef: FIRDatabaseReference = self.channelRef!.child("typingIndicator").child(self.senderId)
  private lazy var usersTypingQuery: FIRDatabaseQuery = self.channelRef!.child("typingIndicator").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true)

  private var newMessageRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
  private var updatedMessageRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?

  private var messages: [JSQMessage] = []
  private var photoMessageMap = [String: JSQPhotoMediaItem]()

  private var localTyping = false
  var channel: Channel? {
    didSet {
      title = channel?.name
    }
  }

  var isTyping: Bool {
    get {
      return localTyping
    }
    set {
      localTyping = newValue
      userIsTypingRef.setValue(newValue)
    }
  }

  lazy var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage = self.setupOutgoingBubble()
  lazy var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage = self.setupIncomingBubble()

  // MARK: View Lifecycle

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.senderId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    observeMessages()

    // No avatars
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    observeTyping()
  }

  deinit {
    if let refHandle = newMessageRefHandle {
      messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
    }
    if let refHandle = updatedMessageRefHandle {
      messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
    }
  }

  // MARK: Collection view data source (and related) methods

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item] // 1
    if message.senderId == senderId { // 2
      return outgoingBubbleImageView
    } else { // 3
      return incomingBubbleImageView
    }
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.senderId == senderId { // 1
      cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.white // 2
    } else {
      cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.black // 3
    }

    return cell
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView?, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    switch message.senderId {
    case senderId:
      return nil
    default:
      guard let senderDisplayName = message.senderDisplayName else {
        assertionFailure()
        return nil
      }
      return NSAttributedString(string: senderDisplayName)
    }
  }

  // MARK: Firebase related methods

  private func observeMessages() {
    messageRef = channelRef!.child("messages")
    let messageQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast:25)

    // We can use the observe method to listen for new
    // messages being written to the Firebase DB
    newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
      let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

      if let id = messageData["senderId"] as String!, let name = messageData["senderName"] as String!, let text = messageData["text"] as String!, text.characters.count > 0 {
        self.addMessage(withId: id, name: name, text: text)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()
      } else if let id = messageData["senderId"] as String!, let photoURL = messageData["photoURL"] as String! {
        if let mediaItem = JSQPhotoMediaItem(maskAsOutgoing: id == self.senderId) {
          self.addPhotoMessage(withId: id, key: snapshot.key, mediaItem: mediaItem)

          if photoURL.hasPrefix("gs://") {
            self.fetchImageDataAtURL(photoURL, forMediaItem: mediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey: nil)
          }
        }
      } else {
        print("Error! Could not decode message data")
      }
    })

    // We can also use the observer method to listen for
    // changes to existing messages.
    // We use this to be notified when a photo has been stored
    // to the Firebase Storage, so we can update the message data
    updatedMessageRefHandle = messageRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
      let key = snapshot.key
      let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

      if let photoURL = messageData["photoURL"] as String! {
        // The photo has been updated.
        if let mediaItem = self.photoMessageMap[key] {
          self.fetchImageDataAtURL(photoURL, forMediaItem: mediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey: key)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  private func fetchImageDataAtURL(_ photoURL: String, forMediaItem mediaItem: JSQPhotoMediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey key: String?) {
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: photoURL)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: INT64_MAX){ (data, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error downloading image data: \(error)")
        return
      }

      storageRef.metadata(completion: { (metadata, metadataErr) in
        if let error = metadataErr {
          print("Error downloading metadata: \(error)")
          return
        }

        if (metadata?.contentType == "image/gif") {
          mediaItem.image = UIImage.gifWithData(data!)
        } else {
          mediaItem.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        guard key != nil else {
          return
        }
        self.photoMessageMap.removeValue(forKey: key!)
      })
    }
  }

  private func observeTyping() {
    let typingIndicatorRef = channelRef!.child("typingIndicator")
    userIsTypingRef = typingIndicatorRef.child(senderId)
    userIsTypingRef.onDisconnectRemoveValue()
    usersTypingQuery = typingIndicatorRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true)

    usersTypingQuery.observe(.value) { (data: FIRDataSnapshot) in

      // You're the only typing, don't show the indicator
      if data.childrenCount == 1 && self.isTyping {
        return
      }

      // Are there others typing?
      self.showTypingIndicator = data.childrenCount > 0
      self.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
    }
  }

  override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {
    // 1
    let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId()

    // 2
    let messageItem = [
      "senderId": senderId!,
      "senderName": senderDisplayName!,
      "text": text!,
    ]

    // 3
    itemRef.setValue(messageItem)

    // 4
    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

    // 5
    finishSendingMessage()
    isTyping = false
  }

  func sendPhotoMessage() -> String? {
    let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId()

    let messageItem = [
      "photoURL": imageURLNotSetKey,
      "senderId": senderId!,
      ]

    itemRef.setValue(messageItem)

    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

    finishSendingMessage()
    return itemRef.key
  }

  func setImageURL(_ url: String, forPhotoMessageWithKey key: String) {
    let itemRef = messageRef.child(key)
    itemRef.updateChildValues(["photoURL": url])
  }

  // MARK: UI and User Interaction

  private func setupOutgoingBubble() -> JSQMessagesBubbleImage {
    let bubbleImageFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    return bubbleImageFactory!.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlue())
  }

  private func setupIncomingBubble() -> JSQMessagesBubbleImage {
    let bubbleImageFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    return bubbleImageFactory!.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGray())
  }

  override func didPressAccessoryButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)) {
      picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    } else {
      picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    }

    present(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)
  }

  private func addMessage(withId id: String, name: String, text: String) {
    if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: name, text: text) {
      messages.append(message)      
    }
  }

  private func addPhotoMessage(withId id: String, key: String, mediaItem: JSQPhotoMediaItem) {
    if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", media: mediaItem) {
      messages.append(message)

      if (mediaItem.image == nil) {
        photoMessageMap[key] = mediaItem
      }

      collectionView.reloadData()
    }
  }

  // MARK: UITextViewDelegate methods

  override func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    super.textViewDidChange(textView)
    // If the text is not empty, the user is typing
    isTyping = textView.text != ""
  }

}

// MARK: Image Picker Delegate
extension ChatViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                             didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)

    // 1
    if let photoReferenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
      // Handle picking a Photo from the Photo Library
      // 2
      let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [photoReferenceUrl], options: nil)
      let asset = assets.firstObject

      // 3
      if let key = sendPhotoMessage() {
        // 4
        asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
          let imageFileURL = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL

          // 5
          let path = "\(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000))/\(photoReferenceUrl.lastPathComponent)"

          // 6
          self.storageRef.child(path).putFile(imageFileURL!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
              print("Error uploading photo: \(error.localizedDescription)")
              return
            }
            // 7
            self.setImageURL(self.storageRef.child((metadata?.path)!).description, forPhotoMessageWithKey: key)
          }
        })
      }
    } else {
      // Handle picking a Photo from the Camera - TODO
    }
  }

  func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with this section of your code:

```
guard let senderDisplayName = message.senderDisplayName else {
    assertionFailure()
    return nil
}
```

`assertionFailure()` must link to another function that runs `assert(false)` or some equivalent to that. `assert(_)` is meant to verify that a particular parameter or comparison returns true, or if it does not, it will crash the app. The app will not crash if it is a production build (like those on the App Store) because asserts are meant for debugging purposes.

Basically, the guard statement is necessary to verify that `message.senderDisplayName` is unwrappable to some value (not nil). If message.senderDisplayName is nil, then there is no point in running the code below the guard and the contents of the guard should be run instead. `assertionFailure()` will crash the app during testing and during production it will be ignored. When it is ignored, nil will be returned for the function and it will continue on as nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing this out to me but what I'm struggling with is if I run all the same code in the sample project you can demo it perfectly on the simulator but when I try and use it in a brand new app basically mirroring what it does but with a few extra view controllers and a tab view controller I get the crash that I reported above? I'm baffled whats doing this on me? What do you think I could be doing wrong @Alec

Comment: Make sure you're running fresh builds on both. It could be that you're building the app for production on the simulator, but I would add a breakpoint at the `assertionFailure()` line to make sure it is called on both. Past that, I don't know what code is inside `assertionFailure()` so I can't really help you there. I am only assuming that `assert(false)` is called, but it could very well be something like `assert([is on simulator])`. I don't know what the code is without guessing.

Comment: [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2) here's the demo code I was working from originally and the completed project can be downloaded from the bottom of the tutorial. I'm going to keep working at this and see what I can come up with and post my findings

Comment: This is beginning to become a different question than what you originally asked. I would recommend making a new question.

Comment: @Futhark If you believe that I answered your original question of why it was crashing, don't forget to mark it as the answer!

Comment: Hi @Elfuthark. As per the request above, are you able to mark this answer as correct? Thanks if you can!